# Using a map to initialize an object

Tags: groovy

I'm having trouble reusing a map to create new objects. The map changes along with the object:

```
def map =  [ id: 0, list: [1,2] ]

class Obj {
    int id = 0
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()
}

for (iterator in 1..10){
    map.id = iterator
    Obj obj = map as Obj
    obj.list.add(iterator)
    println ("Obj.List: ${obj.list.toString()} \nObj.id: ${obj.id}")
    println "map: ${map.list.toString()}"
}
```

Output on the last iteration:

```
1. Obj.List: [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 

2. map: [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Why is the map changing with the Object?

Comment: because you are adding values into the same list defined in the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens to you because you face passing a reference to a list instead of creating its copy. Groovy adds map constructor by default and this constructor in case of class `Obj` is actually the same as:

```
class Obj {
    int id = 0
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()

    Obj(Map map) {
        id = map.id
        list = map.list
    }
}
```

The assignment `list = map.list` means that `obj.list` and `map.list` refer to the same object in the memory and that is why when you add something to the `obj.list` it is also available when you access `map.list`. There are at least two ways you can fix it.

#### 1. Implement your own constructor in `Obj` class

In this case make sure that `obj.list` gets his own fresh new list, e.g.

```
class Obj {
    int id = 0
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()

    Obj(Map map) {
        id = map.id
        list = map.list.clone()
    }
}
```

#### 2. Override `map.list` with a copy after creating an object

In some cases you may want to keep the default constructor as is. In this case you may simply override the `map.list` with a fresh copy of a list, e.g.

```
for (iterator in 1..10){
    map.id = iterator
    Obj obj = map as Obj
    obj.list = map.list.clone()
    obj.list.add(iterator)
    println ("Obj.List: ${obj.list.toString()} \nObj.id: ${obj.id}")
    println "map: ${map.list.toString()}"
}
```

Both options applied produce following console output:

```
Obj.List: [1, 2, 1] 
Obj.id: 1
map: [1, 2]
Obj.List: [1, 2, 2] 
Obj.id: 2
map: [1, 2]
Obj.List: [1, 2, 3] 
Obj.id: 3
map: [1, 2]
Obj.List: [1, 2, 4] 
Obj.id: 4
map: [1, 2]
Obj.List: [1, 2, 5] 
Obj.id: 5
map: [1, 2]
Obj.List: [1, 2, 6] 
Obj.id: 6
map: [1, 2]
Obj.List: [1, 2, 7] 
Obj.id: 7
map: [1, 2]
Obj.List: [1, 2, 8] 
Obj.id: 8
map: [1, 2]
Obj.List: [1, 2, 9] 
Obj.id: 9
map: [1, 2]
Obj.List: [1, 2, 10] 
Obj.id: 10
map: [1, 2]
```